# How to manually do the interaction term in R?

Tags: r, interaction, dummy-variable

For some [reason](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/397998/241453), I need to include the interaction term between two categorical variables manually.
I provided some example below using iris dataset:

```
iris$group <- as.factor(rep(c("a","b")))
str(iris)

#model without interaction 
mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width+Species+group, iris)
summary(mod)

#model with interaction(Species*group)
mod2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width+Species*group, iris)
summary(mod2)
```

As for my understanding from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/127559/241453), we only include the possible combination that is in the main effect (or minus the combination with a reference group).

```
#dummy variables for interaction
int1 <- ifelse(iris$Species=="versicolor" & iris$group=="b", 1, 0)
int2 <- ifelse(iris$Species=="virginica" & iris$group=="b", 1, 0)

#another method for dummy variable for the interaction
iris$int <- interaction(iris$Species, iris$group)
levels(iris$int)
int3 <- ifelse(iris$int=="versicolor.b", 1, 0)
int4 <- ifelse(iris$int=="virginica.b", 1, 0)

#model with dummy variables
mod3 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width+Species+group+int1+int2, iris)
mod4 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width+Species+group+int3+int4, iris)

summary(mod3)
summary(mod4)
summary(mod2)
```

I get the same result here. But, when I tried to apply this concept to my [actual problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/397998/241453), it does not seem correct to me.

Anyone has any idea? or maybe I do this wrongly but get the same result by chance?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sample of the data in the object `rdata` that was on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397998/how-to-add-covariate-x-time-interaction-term-in-poisson-model-in-rrelsurv-packa please?

Comment: @Nishan rdata is a dataset in relsurv package

Comment: Instead of recoding, have you tried using the `relevel()` and `interaction()` functions?

Comment: I tried using interaction() and I only include the interaction that is in the main effect as above, and I get the same result. But, I'm not sure what do you mean by using relevel() function

Comment: I added above how I use the interaction() function

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done easily:

```
iris$int <- paste0(iris$Species, iris$group)
```

However, this way the new variable is not a factor.

The second way as mentioned in the comment above:

```
iris$int <- interaction(iris$Species, iris$group, sep = "")
```

The new variable is a factor.